# edges are still sharp after subdivision surface modifier

Tags: subdivision-surface

Can somebody help me with this problem: why are the highlighted edges still so sharp after the subdivision surface modifier?

Thank you.[image]

Comment: This is the mesh before the subdivision surface:    https://s4.uupload.ir/files/mesh_-q_oqou.jpg

Comment: Well, the first things I'd try is to check for dupes and recalculate normals outside. Although you may have already done this. You are correct, Subdiv Surface interpolates between face angles, so the edge shouldn't be sharp like that (on its own).

Comment: Before applying subdivision, try pressing A, M, B in edit mode, to remove doubles (and possibly holding edges there).

Comment: @ChristopherBennett you are right, there was a problem with the flipped normals. Thank you!

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thank you.